# Android & Guice - Inject Generic typed classes?

Tags: java, android, generics, guice, roboguice

I have a generic type class. I am trying to inject this class, and it doesn't seem to be working. The other solutions I have found go against the whole point of having generics, because the recommend to hard code the type in the module.

```
@Override
protected void configure() {

    this.bind(new TypeLiteral<IServiceClient<Object>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<ServiceClient<Object>>(){});



}
```

Usage

`@Inject IServiceClient<Customer> customerServiceClient`;

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, the type parameter is a useful part of the `Key` (which itself is only composed of a `TypeLiteral` and a binding annotation). Guice anticipates that you will want to treat `IServiceClient<User>` and `IServiceClient<Property>` as two different bindings, so you could easily fulfill them with two different implementations. It sounds like yours is the less-specific case, where you want `MyService<Foo>` to bind to the same implementation class for any `Foo`.

At its root Guice is a map from key to provider, so it's not very easy to bind a wide range of keys in a single statement. Of course you could loop through the different type parameters of `IServiceProvider` that you intend to support, binding each one separately, but it seems like that's the solution "against the whole point of generics" that you anticipated. (I disagree that it's past the point, but agree that the loop is a little unwieldy if you're supporting a wide range of classes as the parameter.)

Because generics are handled through erasure anyway, a better option might be to bind the implementation class once and cast it in the class's constructor:

```
class MyConsumer {
  IServiceProvider<Foo> fooServiceProvider;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Inject
  MyConsumer(IServiceProvider<?> fooServiceProvider) {
    this.fooServiceProvider = (IServiceProvider<Foo>) fooServiceProvider;
  }
}
```

This way Guice will reflectively look for the same `IServiceProvider` implementation no matter what type you intend, and you'll safely cast it yourself. You can wrap the cast up in a static method if you find the warnings ugly.